# Kerio Connect: Backup in progress in queue for a long time

Tags: email, email-server, mac-osx-server, kerio

In the web interface I have messages queuing up, and it tells me that Backup is in progress. This is not my main server, but I am attempting to help with this queue issue.

Apparently this is a long term issue, and happens every now and again. Any hints and tips about how to prevent this happening in future, will be greatly appreciated. I do not want kerio services disturbed by in house kerio processes - That's just a bad programming!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It transpired that it was a DDOS attack - our network was being flooded with data from outside - a quick jig to the firewall, and order was restored :)

But I will keep these answers, they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Kerio Connect are you running?

I have administered Kerio from when it was called Mailserver on all three major platforms and haven't had any issues with backups.

Some questions to assist with diagnosis:

- How big is your mail store?
- How many accounts do you have and how big are they on average?
- Do you have it set to do full backups every time or incremental?
- How is your mail store connected
  to your server? iSCSI? Fibre? Local disks?
- What's the I/O load on your mail
  store location and backup location?
- Is there space on your backup location?
- What medium are you backing up to?

Is there anything in the logs (Kerio or OS X) which hint to any problem that may be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Kerio uses postfix as a MTA and it maintains a database of messages going through server. It really needs to shutdown processes for a while to make a current snapshot but it shouldn't take long. Do you get any errors in the log? Do you have enough space on the target volume?